# WP in subfolder hidden by htaccess, but media links show the subfolder

Tags: url-rewriting, uploads, home-url

The WordPress install is in `/public_html/example`. In the `.htaccess` file in `public_html` I have this code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

In `/public_html/example` I have exactly the same file.

So when I access the site, all the pages have URLs such as `http://example.com/about`. The URL rewriting specified in `.htaccess` is working. But the rewriting does not work for media files, which all have links like `http://example.com/example/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/hello.txt`.

My question: Is it possible to get file links such as `http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/hello.txt` (without the duplication of "example")?

Comment: To do a redirection of URL like `http://example.com/wp-content/`... you need to put a .htaccess file in the directory `/public_html/` or `/public_html/wp-content/`, it's not related to your WordPress installation. Do you have access to one of these directories ?

Comment: @mmm I do. What would I put in the .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to explicitly move the wp-content folder one level up so it resides at `/public_html/wp-content` by defining `WP_CONTENT_DIR` in `wp-config.php`.

For this I'd recommend something more like the second method described in [Giving WordPress Its Own Directory](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory). [Editing wp-config.php](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_wp-content_folder) has an example for the `WP_CONTENT_DIR` change.

The resulting directory structure (relative to `public_html` would look like this:

```
- .htaccess
- index.php
- wp-content
  - ...
- example
  - wp-admin
  - wp-includes
  - ...
```

Bonus:

You can use a `.htaccess` file similar to this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) example/$1 [L] # your WP folder
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ wp/$1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

This way you can set both Home URL and Site URL to `https://example.com` (without `/example`, so it won't be clear at first glance that WordPress is installed in a subfolder. You can then log in via `https://example.com/wp-admin/`

Such a setup is especially useful when using Composer, where WordPress is best installed in a subdirectory like described in Rarst's [Composer in WordPress](http://composer.rarst.net/recipe/site-stack/) guide.